# From what materials can a mikveh be made?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

Reading sources on constructing a mikveh, it seems that the walls and floor should be made of brick or ceramic.  Is any other material possible, such as aluminum, wood, Lexan (plexiglass), or fiberglass?  Reason I ask is that I want to retrofit my existing fiberglass bathtub/shower as part of the structure, since it can't be ripped out of the bathroom wall.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how the mikve construction laws apply to your bathtub/shower. A mikve needs a souce of rainwater, can you get that into your bathtub?

Comment: @mbloch (no) rain!

Comment: I'd build a rainwater tank inside the bathroom next to the tub.  I'd extend the house rain gutter into the tank through the bathroom window from the outside.  I'd build up the tub to become high enough for immersion when sitting.

Comment: Amazing. Kol hakavod. But the laws of mikve construction are very complex and you will need an expert to advise you. I can't imagine it could be done via MY. Maybe you can ask for names of experts here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi David Miller wrote a book called the Secret of a Jew(Sod Netzach Yisrael) ,the purpose of the book was to get Jews who weren't religious to start keeping the Torah. Its a great read even for those who are religious since it gives a glimpse into the world of American Jewry in the early 1900's. Anyhow, Rabbi Miller understood that many women werent going to the mikva for various reasons. So Rabbi Miller sought to find a way that every woman would be able to build their own mikva and immerse in the privacy of their own home. His method of using the water system was very controversial,but nonetheless his intentions were pure .

In the book he gives instructions how to make a very inexpensive mikva from basic materials. In this [link](http://www.homemikveh.org/sotj/sotj.html) one will be able to see his instructions and his thought process. It goes without saying that when it comes to the issur of kares(relations when wife is a nidda) extra caution needs to be taken and an expert Rabbi in the field of mikvos must  be reached before such a project is started. This is just to get an idea of the basics.

Here is a picture of what his basic mikvah construction looked like with details of items needed with their prices from 1930 (see link above):

[image]

For the frame

**Item a.**    8 pieces    1" stock, 12" wide, 30" long (1" x 12" x 2'6")

**Item b.**    4 pieces    1"         2"       48"      (1" x 2" x 4')

**Item c.**    8 pieces    1"        12"       48"      (1" x 12" x 4')

**Item d.**    2 pieces    1"         6"       48"      (1" x 6" x 4')

Total 59 feet at a cost of about 3 cents per foot -**cost**- $1.77

**Item e.**  A box of 6-penny nails - **cost**- .10

For the lining

**Item f.**  72 ft of roofing paper costing about $2 for a roll of 100 ft- **cost**- $1.44

For the outlet

**Item g.**  1 1/2 inch hydrant bib faucet ..................................   .50

**Item h.**  1 1/2 inch by 3 inch all-threaded galvanized (tank) nipple .....   .10

**Item i.**  2 1/2 inch lock nuts and 2 fiber washers .......................   .10

**Item j**.  1 1/2 inch sleeve or coupling ..................................   .15

Total .......................................................... $4.16

Add 10% for unforseen expenses or variation in prices ..........   .42

Total .......................................................... $4.58

Comment: His heterim were quite controversial.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin ,yes I did note that in my answer ,still doesn't take away from his intentions and his brilliance. He was also talking to an audience who vadai weren't  going to the mikva.

Answer (score 0):

It can be made from any material that does not leak, the main issue is that it should not be a vessel

It would seem legally ok to use the tube if you make a hole (by the drain) the size of a pomegranate and then seal it with cement and the cement should also be connected to the structure that is connected to the ground

But the the rain water that is collected in the tank is probably not considered rain water anymore but collected water and it can not be used

---

There is a law that you need (try) to dip into water that is the hight of a hand above the naval when standing

Comment: According to my research, redirecting rainwater through gutters that don't collect water themselves is not considered collection.  C.F. Chabad publications re mikvek constructions.

Comment: @eternalsquire That is correct buy your tank might be a vessel,

Comment: What's the difference between a pool, or 'bor', and a vessel?  In the "kissing" construction there are effectively two pools which connect through a common wall.  I don't see any effective difference between a raised tank and a raised pool in this case.

Comment: @eternalsquire that is the law, maybe because water in a vessel is more in human hands then water in a pit,

Comment: no way to dig a pit indoors.  I'll ask this as a new question.

Comment: @eternalsquire The basic laws of mikva is (by rain water (not spring)) that the water needs to be not in a vesal, and the first  volume (40 soa) needs to be rain water that was not collected  by a human and did not pass over something that can become ritually impure (snow, ice, sea salt ... Is an exception)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39369/discussion-between-eternalsquire-and-hazoriz).