# How does the rainwater enter the bor?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

Tap water that comes from natural springs cannot serve as mikvah due to water pipe and pump system. I am interested then, how does the rainwater enter the bor? If it can not go trough pipes or filters, how is it done?

Comment: Why do you think pipes are a problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only issue is having it sit somewhere before entering the mikveh; redirecting the water is fine, as long as it doesn't get caught on anything in the pipe. That's how most mikvaos are designed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can I ask why is it problematic for rainwater to be caught on anything in the pipe? Doesn't the same thing happen in the spring/river?

Answer (score 2):

Going through pipes is not the issue.
The problem is if somewhere along the length of the pipe there is a slight dip or depression, elbow etc. That place causes the water to be gathered, and it then becomes "drawn" and is no longer rain or spring water.
A mikveh is constructed in such a fashion that the rain water is directed with very carefully placed pipes that do not have a place water can collect.

An excellent resource is "Understanding Mikvah" by Rabbi Schneur Zalman Lesches. PDF is available [here](http://www.kollelmenachem.org/media/pdf/433/juNS4330495.pdf). See page 62.

Comment: Notably, not everyone even agrees tap water is invalid for a Mikvah.

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to this - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79642/8593 Still the question seems to be from the point of view that holds tap water is a problem.